# Why does inspect() think map isn't built in?

Tags: python

The following code returns false

```
import inspect
print(inspect.isbuiltin(map))
```

But the map function is listed under ["built-in" functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Why is it so?

Comment: I does seem odd that `inspect.isbuiltin(__builtins__.map)` would be `False`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `inspect.isbuiltin` will only

> Return true if the object is a built-in *function or method*.

The `map` builtin is a *class*, not a function or method:

```py
>>> map
<class 'map'>
```

In fact, most "built-in functions" that return iterators are implemented as classes; calling them returns optimised instances instead of re-using some generic iterator class.

```py
>>> zip  # zip iterator "function" is also a class
<class 'zip'>
>>> map(str, (1, 2, 34))  # map builds instances of map
<map object at 0x103fa34f0>
```

---

In addition, keep in mind that the term "built-in" has two meanings in Python:

- A compiled object, i.e. *built in*to the interpreter.
- A member of [the `builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), available in every module.

While most `builtins` are compiled for speed, this is no necessity.

If you want to check whether a name is part of `builtins`, do so via the module:

```py
>>> import builtins
>>> hasattr(builtins, "map")
True
>>> hasattr(builtins, "sum")
True
>>> hasattr(builtins, "reduce")
False
```

Comment: Adding to the answer `inspect.isclass(map)` return `True`

Comment: Yes. ```inspect.isbuiltin(sum)``` returns ```True```. ```sum``` is a builtin *function* and not a *type*

Comment: beat me to it :) if we try to run: `print(inspect.getfile(map))` we'll get an error saying: `TypeError: <class 'map'> is a built-in class`

Comment: In addition, `help(map)` also clearly shows that it is a class ;-).

Comment: Also worth to note that `map` was a "built-in" in python2 and it became a "built-in type" only in python3